# April Fools: Yes Minister

Tags: meaning

Way off topic, but since this is April 1st, I'd like to post a couple of clips from one of my favorite shows - "Yes (Prime) Minister".  This British comedy-show from the early 1980s, follows member of Parliament Jim Hacker; firs as a minister, later as the Prime Minister of Britain.  He frequently cross swords with Sir Humphrey Appleby; Oxford educated, and head of the Civil Service in his ministry.  Sir Humphrey *loves* long words...  In the crossfire between these two, are Bernard Wooly, the Minister's personal secretary.  Loyal to both the civil service he's part of and the Minister he serves.

I have included links to two of Sir Humphrey's more *spectacular* monologues:    Just enjoy them... **or look-up the words he use in a dictionary and post them here - or maybe "translate" them into *normal* English and post them here.**

I for one, would really like to know the meaning - and other suitable uses - of the word *"epistemological"*... In fact, both speeches could be translated into *normal* English...

Both happens after Hacker becomes Prime Minister.

+++

Prime Minister Hacker has been answering questions in Parliament, and was *particularly* satisfied with one of them.  So Sir Humphrey burst his bubble:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8keZbZL2ero

Tired of Sir Humphrey always sneaking into Number 10 Downing Street from the building next door - where Sir Humphrey *officially* works, PM Hacker has had the lock of the connecting door changed.  Here he has just snick in by the window - setting off an alarm and summoning guards - after being denied entry by the front door of Number 10:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYz_A_1xRqc

Sir Humphrey's Goodbye... (before Hacker becomes PM):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-FxrQI_Ymk

+++

Bonus (sadly with less Sir Humphrey's monologues):

The Civil Service:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPx2503UiKc

Who reads the papers:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGscoaUWW2M

Opinion polls:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0ZZJXw4MTA

Choosing the next Prime Minister (The other man is Sir Arnold, the previous Cabinet Secretary):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5P34nJzsaY

Diplomatic options:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3zNCg55kiw

Comment: I know I shouldn't, I know I shouldn't, but +1!

Comment: Guys, I can't disagree that the post is off-topic, but can we wait til midnight to actually close it?

Comment: @DanBron: Well, I thought about it, but then I remembered that [we hate fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). Also, in this case, I don't see why anyone would need to write an answer--I guess closing prevents extended commentary, but people will still be able to view and enjoy the post all day! Relevant SE meta post about April Fool's posts: [Do we need a “no-points” option for Fun/Joke Posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85682/do-we-need-a-no-points-option-for-fun-joke-posts)

Comment: That's just the [dog's milk](https://youtu.be/NEu0o62ycmg).

Comment: I'm tempted to flag this as an improper april fools joke.  A proper april fools joke admits to being a april fools joke at the end, not the start.  Or are you planning to edit this into a proper question and force us to reopen it?  You and your pranks.